# Batch apex is updating only one recod and throwing error:uncomitted work pending

Tags: apex, batch

Hi I have written a batchapex to update the records from Callout Response, but it is updating only one record and showing this error in logs
Error:You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.
.Can anyone help me.
Please see the code below

```
global class AccllBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,   Database.AllowsCallouts  {


 public String query = 'Select id, name,Key from Opportunity where Key!=null';// it has 10 records
 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
 }

     global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> records) {         
          List<Opportunity> OppIn= new List<Opportunity>();
        for ( integer i = 0; i< records.size(); i++ ){
             Opportunity opp = [Select Id,Probability from Opportunity where Id=:records[i].Id];
      system.debug('@@@Current Opp'+opp);
         try {                  

             AccSetting1__c accl = AccSetting1__c.getorgDefaults();
                HTTP h = new HTTP();
                HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();

                Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(accl.UserName__c + ':' + accl.Password_del__c);
                 String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
                r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

                r.setMethod('GET');
                r.setTimeout(120000);
               String ProjectID= records[i].Key;
               String baseEndPoint = 'EndpointURl';//it has EndpointURl

               r.setEndpoint(baseEndPoint);
               HTTPResponse resp = new HTTPResponse();
               resp = h.send(r);
               system.debug('@@@'+resp.getbody());
               String result=resp.getbody();
               Integer StatusCode=resp.getStatusCode();

          if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {      

        if(StatusCode==200){

                  List<Object> lst_JsonParse = (List<Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(result);


                      String  Probability;
                 for(Object obj : lst_JsonParse)

                  {

                   Map<String,Object> mp_StrObj = (Map<string,Object>)obj;
                   if(mp_StrObj.get('id')==1234){
                       system.debug('hello');
                       Object value0 =mp_StrObj.get('value');
                       system.debug('1844testvalue'+value0);
                       Probability=String.valueOf(value0);

                 }


             system.debug(mp_StrObj.get('value'));
             system.debug(mp_StrObj.get('id'));

            }   
           opp.Probability=Decimal.valueOf(Probability);//0


          OppIn.add(opp);

          }             

          }


         }
          catch (Exception e) {         
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'LN:' + e.getLineNumber() );           
          }
       }
          update OppIn;

    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){    
    }


}
```

executing the batch apex class:

```
AccllBatch BS =  new AccllBatch ();

Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(BS, 10);
```

Comment: You are doing next steps in loop for list of record: 1. Select opportunity,. 2. Do callout. 3. update opportunity (that is DML),  4. Go to step 1. 5. Go to step 2. Opps, you are trying to do callout after DML, throw exception.I have few suggestions about your code. Do not query opportunities inside `execute` method. You can already query needed fields in `start` by means of query locator. Rewrite code avoiding soql in loops, dml in loops.

Answer (score 2):

Because you [can't make a callout after you have done DML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=You+have+uncommitted+work+pending) (your `update OppIn;`), you need to make the callouts first and then update the records after all the callouts. So collect the `OppIn` records in a list, and do the update after the loop over the records that makes the callouts.

(Also note that there is no need to query `Opportunity` again inside the `execute` method; you can just query all the fields you need in the `start` method and those will be passed into the `execute method`. You can also use static SOQL so the compiler checks the query.)